# The number of bytes read and unsigned numbers

Tags: io, range, go, unsigned

As an example to clarify my question, in Google Go 1.0, the following interface is defined in the ["io" package](http://golang.org/pkg/io/#Reader):

```
type Reader interface {
    Read(p []byte) (n int, err error)
}
```

Especially the result parameter list `(n int, err error)` intrigues me. Intrinsically the number of bytes can not be negative, according to the documentation of the interface:

> It returns the number of bytes read (0 <= n <= len(p))[...]

In C the reason to use `int` was the in-band value `-1` to signal an error condition (see [Effective Go: Multiple return values](http://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#multiple-returns)). Because of multiple return values, special in-band values are not necessary.

There exists the [type `uint`](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Numeric_types) in Go 1.0.

What is the specific reason for using `int` versus `uint` in the case of values that only use the positive range [0,∞) without the need for having special in-band values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The de facto numeric type for integers in most cases is `int`. For example, `len(x)` and `cap(x)` return `int` values even though those too cannot be negative. In most cases returning an int helps avoid type conversions between different numeric types.

So yes, `Read()` could have returned a `uint`, but this would make it slightly more unwieldy to work with.

Answer (score 5):

The de facto numeric type for integers is int. This is partly because signed int overflow in a more obvious way.
A small overflow of an uint ends up looking like a valid value, but a small overflow of a signed int will be negative and panic in places expecting a positive integer, eg. slicing.

This is important because you'll commonly take the 'n' from Read() and slice 'p' to that length.

eg.

```
n, err := a.Read(p)
p = p[:n]
processReadData(p)
```